# Why is pandoc not recognising package command sequences when converting TeX to docx?

Tags: overleaf, pandoc, msword

I am attempting to use pandoc to convert a .tex file to a .docx file.

When I use the command line to do so via `pandoc foo.tex -s -o foo.docx`, the produced foo.docx compiles fairly nicely but due to unrecognised commands `\notag` and `\texorpdfstring` in my math environments (I'm unsure what package the first one requires but I do know that the second one requires the package `hyperref`). To illustrate, pandoc outputs the below error:

```
unexpected control sequence \notag
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\tag", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math \begin{gathered}
  x_{2}=\frac{1}{2}[(x_{1}+x_{2})-(x_{1}-x_{2})]=\frac{1}{2}[A_{\textrm{in}}\cos{(\omega_{\textrm{in}}t+\phi_{\textrm{in}})}-A_{\textrm{out}}\cos{(\omega_{\textrm{out}}t+\phi_{\textrm{out}})}]\notag\end{gathered}, rendering as TeX:
  xtrm{out}})}]\notag\end{gathered}
```

And, true to its word, my .docx document has raw TeX instead of formatted math.

However, when I compile my .tex file using TeXShop, it compiles fine, and the local packages seem to be used (I did use the appropriate `usepackage` options in my preamble). How do I make pandoc also use these packages?

I am also able to use Overleaf, but could not find an option to export the tex there to .docx format.

Comment: I fear you are misinformed: pandoc does not process but a subset of LaTeX syntax: it does not go through TeX at all. Try [TeX4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht) instead.